# Is there a process to remap/switch CANTX/CANRX pins STM32H7 FDCAN module?

Tags: stm32, gpio, can-bus, peripherals

Testing out an STM32 with an FDCAN module (updated from the older BxCAN peripheral). CAN Classic at 500kbps.

I am running into an issue that when using the default pair of pins (D0/D1 in my case) I get expected behavior, but when switching the pins to the secondary option (B8/B9) using GPIO remapping, I get strange output on the bus.

I tried baud settings and options like protocol exception. Nothing seems to explain where this scope output is coming from.

I'm using the HAL to get this working, so I'm certain I'm not missing any registers on remapping. I've DeInit and ReInit the FDCAN module, started/stopped, etc. There seems to be no documented "process" for remapping pins. The entire FDCAN section of the reference module doesn't have the letters GPIO.

[image: Scope capture of the strange CAN bus message]

**Picture:** Yellow is the CANTX 0-3V signal (low is dominant). Purple is the CAN+ signal that idles at 2.5V and pulls past ~3.5V on a dominant. There is nothing else on this line, so I'm not concerned about the sawtoothing. The large initial CAN "SOF" pulse is wrong for timing. The long recessives are nonsense. Then the small value 1 bits are of the correct 2uS pulses for 500kbps. Changing the data put into the FDCAN FIFO makes no difference, the output is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

After sending this message, the INIT bits were set in the `FDCAN->CCCR` register. There were values in the error counters. Indicates an internal error. I was using the HAL as a time saver, but it was over-writting my desired GPIO settings.

I would set the pins B8/B9 to AF mode for FDCAN. Then call FDCAN_DeInit/Init, which via an MSP_INIT callback also calls GPIO Init, but for the original D0/D1 pins. Meaning the B8/B9 I set, and the D0/D1 pins were enabled at the same time.

This is an obvious problem. The HAL is fine for prototyping, but careful because it will try and "help". Undefined behavior at best and I normally wouldn't even post such a dumb mistake.

*However...* Maybe someone else finds it interesting that whatever the FDCAN state machine is doing here, makes this unique output seen in the scope picture. I initially didn't double check my pin setup, because it looked right, I was getting output on the scope, just the *wrong* output. I spent much more time going over peripheral settings and data I was feeding to it.